# Scale down a background image using css to fill the screen

Tags: html, css, background-image, fullscreen, scale

I am trying to use the technique described as technique #2 at the following URL:
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

to set a web page background image that shrinks in size when the window is resized.

My HTML is as following

```
<div class="bg">
  <img src="images/bg.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

And my style definition is as following.

```
.bg {
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
.bg img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
}
```

This works perfectly when the image is smaller than the screen and it needs to be sized up.
But in case of shrinking a big image, it doesn't work and I just get a huge image centred on my screen.

I need my image to be able to shrink, cover the entire background, preserve aspect ration.
I cannot use body bg or whatsoever because I need to be able to change the image in a slideshow.

EDIT:
I HAVE to have the HTML structure as `<div><img/></div>`

EDIT 2:
The reason I cannot change the structure (or at least that's what I think) is that I am using script at:
http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js
to cycle several images, and that script doesn't allow me to change anything of the way the HTML is structured. If anyone knows how to use it with background images or suggest a totally different script that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have answered your question. Try it and let me know if it works for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to use `<img>` tags to produce the image, simply delete the `height` declaration from your CSS; the image should maintain aspect ratio **and** resize appropriately if you just have `width` specified. (Alternatively you could specify `height` and delete `width` as well, but specifying `width` is the industry norm.

---

For a CSS background method, try this, instead:

```
.bg {
background-image: url('images/bg.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center center;
background-clip: border-box;
background-origin: padding-box;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
}
```

It requires **CSS3**, but will work in somewhat-old browsers (`-moz-background-size` is for FF3.6; FF4+ uses the default `background-size`). This method uses the CSS `background-image` property which is preferred to your method.

The reason for this is that the background image is not part of the *meaningful content* of your site page, but rather part of the *styling* (it's a background image, so it belongs in the background). Therefore, it should be handled using **Cascading *Style* Sheets**.

Comment: As I said: "I cannot use body bg or whatsoever because I need to be able to change the image in a slideshow.", but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Bishoy And you cannot use JS to achieve this? I ask because you are calling it a background image, yet seem to insist on using it as if it were content.

Comment: I don't insist, I am just not an expert (hence asking questions here) and I am guessing that is the only way to do it.
I will edit and add more details so maybe if you see the whole picture could help me better

Comment: @Bishoy I've edited my post and added a method for you to try for the HTML `<img>` approach.

Comment: Thanks TylerH, that seemed to work with the first image, but then when the cycle kicked in, the next images stayed at the first size when the page first loaded and neither shrinks or expand.

Comment: @Bishoy I can't check, but Morven has also provided a (slightly different) answer using more-or-less the same method that might work on all the images. In the future, I'd recommend not using such a complex jQuery script until you're slightly more familiar with the framework ;-) It can lead to headaches like this!

Comment: Ok can you please tell me an alternative, how other people are doing slideshows in the background? I remember seeing this more than once.

Comment: @Bishoy I am pretty sure you can do slideshows just using CSS. For example: [This site](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/) explains it, and [This site](http://www.queness.com/post/14329/pure-css3-sliders-and-tutorials) has some tutorials as well.

Comment: @bishoy Why don't you just crop/resize the image and put it up? It will save the headache for all.

Comment: I didn't know I could do all of that by CSS by itself, but I couldn't see how can I use this on background-image! or you mean if I used it on my div/img it should work with less hassel?

Comment: @Bishoy Well, if the images you're trying to display in the slideshow are part of the content (like an image gallery on an artist's website), then the `<img>` method is okay. But if what you want is simply a background that changes similarly to a slideshow, then I still think you should use CSS `background-image` property, maybe with CSS Transforms. I've never done such a thing before, though, and I don't have time to look into it right now, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the help, I will keep trying out all possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the styles from your `.bg` div and apply the following styles to your `img` tag.

```
.bg img {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

P.S. Since you are going to use this as a slideshow, I would suggest you to change the class `.bg` to `.slideshow` so that it's semantically meaningful.

Comment: that didn't work
just showed a fixed size image in the middle of the screen with the rest of the page content showed below it (not over it)

Comment: About the naming, this is just for the discussion, my actual code is in ASP.net and I am creating the class names on the fly